# auto renewal certificates in servers

Tags: certificate

I wonder if it is possible to automaticaly renew all the certificates that are in server, then we dont need be worry if the cerficates date are about to expire. 
I tried to configure auto Enrollment but im not 100% sure if i did correct.
I've followed this link to configure:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/core-network-guide/cncg/server-certs/configure-server-certificate-autoenrollment